# How to create a custom validator if one of the formArray has value?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form like below which contains two formArray,I want to send the request if one of the form arrays has at least value.

```
  statementForm = this.fb.group({
    favor: this.fb.array([], ),
    against: this.fb.array([],),
  });
```

This function is used to add the for or against statements :

```
  createItem(name = '') {
    return this.fb.group({
      statement: name,
    });
  }
```

Comment: How are values added to the arrays?

Comment: i have updated the question , hope it clears your doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own validator that you can attach to the form group.

The validator can check that values exist in the arrays, and return either an object indicating a validation error or null.

When you submit the form, you can check that the form is valid before submitting.

```js
private getEmptyArrayValidator(...arrayNames: string[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {      
    const arrays: FormArray[] = arrayNames.map(x => group.get(x) as FormArray);
    // Check that at least one array has at least one item.
    // If you need more complex validation logic, this can be changed easily.
    if (arrays.some(array => array.controls.length > 0)) {
      return null;
    }

    return {
      emptyArrays: 'Lists are empty'
    };
  }
}
```

You can attach this to your form group when you create it:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const validator = this.getEmptyArrayValidator('favor', 'against');
  this.statementForm = this.fb.group({
    favor: this.fb.array([]),
    against: this.fb.array([])
  }, { validators: validator });
}
```

And then check the form validity when the form is submitted:

```js
onSubmit() {
  if (!this.statementForm.valid) {
    return;
  }

  console.log('submitting');
}
```